# Connect LG 27UL850-W monitor through USB-C to ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen2

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, thinkpad, usb-c, lg-monitor

I'm using a [LG 27UL850-W](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UL850-W-4k-uhd-led-monitor) with a ThinkPad X1 Yoga Gen.2 on Windows 10.
I need to get the monitor working through USB-C but I'm only getting "No signal detected".

What I tried:

- Installing the driver ("LG HDR 4K Win 10 Driver LG_HDR_4K.zip") failed because the monitor is not detected.
- HDMI works, so the monitor works (but no 4K)
- Different USB-C ports
- Different USB-C cables, inkl. the one shipped with the monitor

Comment: Try to install [Critical Intel Thunderbolt Software and Firmware Updates](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/ca/en/solutions/ht508988/?clickid=1qLzLoX-jxyJTlPwUx0Mo3cTUknW6OTPNxaGwc0&irgwc=1&PID=221109&acid=ww%3Aaffiliate%3Abv0as6).

Comment: Make sure you have the right Intel GFX Driver v17.4.78.21 & FW, I BELIEVE this might be the same as @harrymc's answer by coincidence: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x1-yoga-type-20jd-20je-20jf-20jg/solutions/HT508988-CRITICAL-INTEL-THUNDERBOLT-SOFTWARE-AND-FIRMWARE-UPDATES-THINKPAD

Comment: @Tom: Have you advanced with the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Had a similiar issue with an LG monitor and a Lenovo Yoga X1.
Could solve this by enabling the HDR modus for this screen in Windows 10.

Answer (score -3):

This Monitor does not have Thunderbolt, and your Laptop Has Thunderbolt.
In This Case You will need an adapter to convert from Type C to HDMI from Your Laptop and then connect your Monitor via HDMI